# PHP: how to detect current column in code (eq. __COLUMN__)?

Tags: php, constants, line

I need to get unique identificator for current place of function call in code (for using it in template).
So, i need something like:

```
$uid = __FILE__ . __LINE__ . __COLUMN__;
```

Does PHP have anything like `__COLUMN__`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so, no.

There is no mention of such a thing in the [magic constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) section of the manual.

However, it stands to reason one shouldn't be needing that too badly. If a line of source code is so long that it needs the column number as an information, it should probably be broken up.

Comment: @Mikhail ah, I see now what you need this for. Hmm, sadly I don't think there is a solution

Comment: I need it for makes my code (smarty templates) more cleaner.

Example:
{foreach array(1,2,3) as $number}
 {cycle values="foo,bar"}
{/foreach}

{foreach array(1,2,3) as $number}
 {cycle values="foo,bar"}
{/foreach}

function smarty_function_cycle($params, $template)
{
 if (@$params['name'] == '')
 {
  $trace = debug_backtrace();
  $params['name'] = $trace[1]['file'] . trace[1]['line'] . trace[1]['column'];
 }
}

Comment: Without it i must use "name" in all cycles:
{foreach array(1,2,3) as $number}
 {cycle values="foo,bar" name="cycle1"}
{/foreach}

{foreach array(1,2,3) as $number}
 {cycle values="foo,bar" name="cycle2"}
{/foreach}